# Parse json data to view as an image in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, json, image

I have images and texts  as json data.

```
"imageCollection": {
"Name": "Anna",
"imageUrl":"https://xxx/xxx/img.jpg?t=5657565",
},
```

I used this approach to parse json data into image but I want to append image and text side by side in my popup window.

```
document.getElementById("img").src=                    
jsonData.imageCollection.logo;
```

what i wrote before to parse json data to html

```
 document.getElementById("host").innerHTML= 
 jsonData.imageCollection.Name
```

how should i merge this two method in one to append together? any Suggestion please?
my popup.html

```
<div id="host">
 <image id="img"></image>
</div>
```

Comment: I think it should be like below statement.
   document.getElementById("host").innerHTML = jsonData.imageCollection.imageUrl;

Comment: no then it shows the url as a viewnot image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using src property of image

```
document.getElementById("IMAGE_TAG_ID").src = jsonData.imageCollection.imageUrl;
```

replace IMAGE_TAG_ID to your image tag id.