# "getElementByID().innerHTML + .src" declare in ONE SINGLE method instead two different methods

Tags: javascript, json, innerhtml, getelementbyid, src

I have images and texts as json data.

```
"imageCollection": {
"Name": "Anna",
"imageUrl":"https://xxx/xxx/img.jpg?t=5657565",
},
```

I used this approach to parse some json data into image and some into text in my popup window separatly.

to view as an image:

```
document.getElementById("img").src=                    
jsonData.imageCollection.logo;
```

to view as a plain text

```
document.getElementById("host").innerHTML= 
jsonData.imageCollection.Name
```

how should i merge this two method into one single output? any Suggestion please? my popup.html

```
<div id="host">
 <image id="img"></image>
</div>
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are expecting. The question is a bit unclear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse json data to view as an image in chrome extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32647527/parse-json-data-to-view-as-an-image-in-chrome-extension)

Comment: What is your question? How to show both the image and name together?

Comment: Is there something wrong with concatenating those 2 lines and wrapping them in `function () {}`?

Comment: @sqykly yes i am having trouble wrapping them together

Comment: @JaromandaX  that question was edited. and ans was for previous question . read before you comment.

Comment: @user12 the question looks identical to me. If you edited your last question to be exactly like this new question how the frack am I supposed to know what the question used to be. Lose the attitude

Comment: You still got it wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the image with the title as a caption you want to do something like this:

```
<div class="popup">
    <img id="img" />
    <span id="host"></span>
</div>
```

Here's the JS with the elements stored in variables for clarity:

```
var image = document.getElementById('img');
var host = document.getElementById('host');

image.src = jsonData.imageCollection.logo;
host.innerHTML = jsonData.imageCollection.Name;
```

In your original HTML, you were setting the image source (good) and then by setting `host.innerHTML` you were replacing the entire `<img>`. To get around this I wrapped both the `img` tag and created a new `span` tag that will hold the image name in another div so they can be styled together.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
<div id="host">
 <image id="img"></image>
 <div id="nme"></name>
</div>

document.getElementById("img").src = jsonData.imageCollection.logo; 

document.getElementById("nme").innerHTML= jsonData.imageCollection.Name
```

Comment: i have this bunch of code already . but i need to merge them in one . as when i run the code only the last method is beig declared but i need to appear them both image + text from json data

Comment: This is different to your code - I have an additional <div> tag and the Id used is different. This code will display the image with the text underneath. Please read and understand the code before marking it down